# Требуется помощь в составлении алгоритма

Tags: python-3.x, excel

уважаемые читатели. Есть задача: существует таблица в экселе с текстом. Этот текст надо взять и перенести в таблицу в ворде. Параллельно часть данных нужно внести в другую таблицу в эксель. Исходная таблица каждый раз в новом файле. Целевая таблица в ворде тоже каждый раз новая. Целевая таблица в эксель одна и та-же и внутри неё нужно вставить строки основываясь на значении в ячейки в исходной таблице. Подскажите как подступиться к задаче?
Я понимаю что для людей постоянно пишущих код задача может быть тривиальная, но я инженер-строитель который в качестве хобби пытается автоматизировать часть рутинной работы. Есть начальные знания в python по этому если задачу можно реализовать на нём то будет замечательно.

Comment: Я бы написал макрос (программу на VBA) в постоянном файле (это который "целевая эксель-таблица"). Если речь о тупом копипасте с места на место - ничего сложного.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Алгоритм не подскажу, но советую параллельно посмотреть, не реализовать ли это на макросах Microsoft. Возможно, есть и +/- решение, так как задача не выглядит супернеобычной.

Comment: А вот комментарий Духа сообщества меня в тупик поставил...

Comment: @Сергей Дух говорит следующее - с техзаданиями на программирование надо идти на биржу фриланса. А тут надо задавать вопросы по конкретной узкой проблеме или кусочку кода, который не работает или работает не так, как хочется. Тут помогают, а не делают за вас...

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, идея понятна - т.е. и вопросы типа "как подступиться?" - не сюда. (Тут не просили её сделать. Вот я, например, дал ответ (он, кстати, совпал с вашим). Мог быть ответ со ссылкой знакомой.)

Comment: @Сергей "Как подступиться" - это на курсах обучения или "читаем программирование для чайников". Потому как крупно алгоритм очевиден - открыть файл-источник, открыть файл-приёмник, выбрать данные-источник, выбрать место-приёмник, скопировать, сохранить, закрыть. И не надо быть семи пяток во лбу...